# pandas dataframe extract spectrograms

Tags: python, pandas, conv-neural-network

I have a pandas dataframe that has 8528 rows × 18287 columns. Each row has a label. How can I extract 8528 spectrograms from each row and save these spectrograms in a variable in order to feed them into an Alexnet for training process?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use [scipy.signal.spectrogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html)?

Comment: @maciek97x                                                                                                                                         No I didn't How it works?

Comment: You can pass time series to it and it will return frequencies, times and spectrogram. For example:  `f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x,)`.